# Check if user input string is empty/undef?

Tags: perl

Here is the entirety of my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
#use P4;

print "enter location of master_testplan.conf:";
my $master_testplan_conf = <>;

if (chomp($master_testplan_conf) eq "")
{
    $master_testplan_conf = 'suites/MAP/master_testplan.conf';
}

print ":" . $master_testplan_conf . ":";
```

referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045644/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-empty-in-perl), I thought this would work. However it's not getting the default value inside the if statement for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: side effects are bad. I mean - isn't there a side-effect free version of chomp out there in perl-land?

Comment: `s/^\s+|\s+$//r`, starting from Perl 5.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) does not work that way.  It directly modifies the variable passed to it and returns the number of characters chomped off.  Do this instead:

```
chomp $master_testplan_conf;
if ($master_testplan_conf eq "") {
    # etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`chomp` modifies its argument and does not return it, so you have to rewrite your condition into something like:

```
chomp($master_testplan_conf);
if ($master_testplan_conf eq "") {
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
..It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments..
```

So you need to chomp first and then compare to the empty string. For example:

```
chomp($master_testplan_conf = <>);
if ($master_testplan_conf eq "") {
    // set default value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

Chomp changes the string, and returns the number of character *chomped*. After that input line, `chomp $master_testplan_conf` is most likely to `1`, so you're comparing `1` to the null string.

You can do it this way:

```
chomp ( $master_testplan_conf = <> );
```

if you want to do everything on a single line.

That will read your input and do the chomp in one step. Also, the `<>` operator will take files from the command line and `<>` will be the first line of the first file on the command line. If you don't want to do that, use `<STDIN>`:

```
chomp ( $master_testplan_conf = <STDIN> );
```

You may want to sanitize your user's input. I would at least remove any leading and ending blanks:

```
$master_testplan_conf =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;  # Oh, I wish there was a "trim" command!
```

This way, if the user accidentally presses spacebar a few times, you don't pick up the spaces. You also may want to test for the file's existence too:

```
if ( not -f $master_testplan_conf ) {
    die qq(File "$master_testplan_conf" not found);
}
```

I also recommend to use:

```
if ( not defined $master_testplan_conf or $master_testplan_conf eq "" ) {
```

for your `if` statement. This will test whether `$master_test_conf` is actually defined and not merely a null string. Right now, this doesn't matter since the user has to at least enter a `\n`. The `$master_testplan_conf` stroll will never be null.

However, it may matter if you decide to use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).

Answer (score 0):

A regex can be handy to check without altering anything:

```
if ($master_testplan_conf =~ /^\s*$/)
{
    $master_testplan_conf = 'suites/MAP/master_testplan.conf';
}
```

to check undef also:

```
if (!defined $master_testplan_conf ||  $master_testplan_conf =~ /^\s*$/)
{
    $master_testplan_conf = 'suites/MAP/master_testplan.conf';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're interested in the *file* and not the *string*, per se, so use Perl file tests, instead.  In this case, use the file test for existence (`-e`):

```
if (-e $master_testplan_conf) {
```

This gets to the heart of the matter and lets you know whether the input exists in the file system, or not.

Comment: I see nothing in the question to suggest that the OP is actually trying to determine whether a file exists.